# JPanel not rendering when added to other JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

This is my Game Class:

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    Thread thread;
    private boolean running = true;
    private double FPS = 1.0/60.0;
    private Level level;

    public Game(){
        level = new LevelOne();
        level.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        add(level);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this, "Game");
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        double firstTime = 0;
        double lastTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0;
        double passedTime = 0;
        double updateTime = 0;
        double timer = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0;
        int rendered = 0;
        int updates = 0;


        while (running) { 
            firstTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0;
            passedTime = firstTime - lastTime;
            lastTime = firstTime;

            updateTime += passedTime;

            while(updateTime > FPS){
                updates++;
                update();
                updateTime -= FPS;
            }

            render();
            rendered++;
            if((System.nanoTime() / 1000000000) - timer > 1){
                timer += 1;
                System.out.println("FPS:"+rendered+" Updates:"+updates);
                updates = 0;
                rendered = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void update() {

    }

    private void render() {
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        level.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Game game = new Game();
        frame.add(game);
        game.start();
    }

}
```

My LevelOne class:
    package Game;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LevelOne extends Level {
    private BufferedImage spriteSheet;
    private BufferedImage[] player = new BufferedImage[4]; //0 = down, 1 = right, 2 = up, 3 = left
    private int dir = 0;
    private String UP = "W";
    private String DOWN = "S";
    private String LEFT = "A";
    private String RIGHT = "D";
    private int speedX = 0;
    private int speedY = 0;

    public LevelOne(){
        try {
            spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(new File("images/sprites.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            player[i] = spriteSheet.getSubimage((i * 18), 0, 18, 28);
        }

        this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                String key = e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
                if (key.equals(UP)) {
                    dir = 2;
                    speedY = -5;
                } else if (key.equals(LEFT)) {
                    dir = 3;
                    speedX = -5;
                } else if (key.equals(RIGHT)) {
                    dir = 1;
                    speedX = 5;
                } else if (key.equals(DOWN)) {
                    dir = 0;
                    speedY = 5;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                String key = e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
                if (key.equals(UP)) {
                    speedY = 0;
                } else if (key.equals(LEFT)) {
                    speedX = 0;
                } else if (key.equals(RIGHT)) {
                    speedX = 0;
                } else if (key.equals(DOWN)) {
                    speedY = 0;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(player[dir], 0, 0, 18, 28, null);
    }
}
```

LevelOne extends Level, which is currently empty(And extends JPanel), I'm not sure if I need to add anything to Level.  I just dont get what I need to do to make the player image show up...

And sorry if my code is sloppy, I'm trying to get into higher level Java, and im not sure if I am just approaching it wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't call `level.repaint` from within `paintComponent`

Comment: Should I call it inside of `render` then?

Comment: And `Level` might look like...?

Comment: At the moment, `Level` is empty, dont know what methods to add to it, though it does extend JPanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Six things...

1. Don't call `level.repaint` from within the `paintComponent` method of `Game`, this could cause an infinite loop of repaint requests which is going to screw with your frame rate.  Consider calling it within your render method
2. `paintComponent` should never `public`, there's no reason for anybody to ever call it directly.
3. Use key bindings over `KeyListener`, they will solve focus related issues. [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)
4. Move `frame.setVisible` AFTER `frame.add(game);`, in fact, it really should the last thing you do
5. Make sure your images are loading properly
6. Set the layout manager for `Game` to `BorderLayout`

Comment: I moved `frame.setVisible` to the end, and that fixed the problem, thank you :)

Comment: @em202020 Watch out for the rest, they will come back to bite you